# Internet Checksum function move 8bits or not

Tags: c, checksum, rfc

This is my implementation of the [Internet Checksum](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1071) (RFC 1071):

```
static unsigned short 
compute_checksum(unsigned short *addr, unsigned int count) {

  register unsigned long sum = 0;
  while (count > 1) {
    sum += * addr++;
    count -= 2;
  }

  //if any bytes left, pad the bytes and add
  if(count > 0) {

 sum+=*(unsigned char*)addr;// left move 8 bits or not? 
  }

  //Fold sum to 16 bits: add carrier to result
  while (sum>>16) {
      sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
  }

  //one's complement
  sum = ~sum;
  return ((unsigned short)sum);
}
```

when meet the odd byte, why we don't need left move 8 bits like this,and RFC does't left move 8 bits too. why? I think this is right one

```
 sum += (*(unsigned char*)addr << 8) & 0xFF00;
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: Which RFC are you referring to?

Comment: [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1071) @Ja͢ck ,I read this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted from the RFC is correct for a littleendian machine.  On a bigendian machine, your shifted solution would be necessary.

With an odd number of bytes, a (theoretical) 0 byte is added on to the end of the sequence.  So the last byte XX should be treated as a short with byte sequence XX 00, which needs to be handled differently depending on the endianness of your machine.

Here's one way to handle it correctly for either endianness:

```
if (count > 0) {
    unsigned char temp[2];
    temp[0] = *(unsigned char *) addr;
    temp[1] = 0;
    sum    += *(unsigned short *) temp;
}
```

For those of you who don't believe the RFC code is wrong, I refer you [to this linux source](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/lib/checksum.c#L49), where it is clear that the littleendian case and the bigendian case must be treated differently in the way I described.  The linux code is a little more complicated because it handles unaligned buffers.

Comment: can I say the left shifted 8 bits is not necessary.no matter what endianness it is. if I checksum bytes with the same checksum method, the result will be the same.e.g. sum+=*(unsigned char*)addr;  add a odd byte ABCD + AB00(littleEndian) or ABCDD+00AB(bigEndian),although it is not nomal, it can be checked .

Comment: if I use my own checksum method to receive the packet,then it is can be received. If I want to send the packet to others, endianess should be considered. Is that  right?

Comment: These days, networking devices (ethernet cards, routers, etc) do checksumming in hardware and will reject your packet if it has the wrong checksum.  So you will not even be able to send the packet to yourself except from one process to another on the same machine.

Comment: if I change the code to solve two endianess  sum += (*addr ) & 0xFF00;   Is that compatible with the two situations? *addr contains 16bits. ABCD => littleEndian: CDAB+ 00FF  bigEndian: ABCD +FF00

Comment: the code in the RFC does not care which endian your machine is, The internet is big endian, but as has been demonstrated the code works for either endian as each checksum byte carries to its neighbor.

Comment: @Jasen No, you are wrong.  If you run the code in the RFC on both a big and little endian machine with an odd sized packet, you will get different checksums.  Try it yourself before you call me wrong.

Comment: @JS1 thank you for your elaboration.And I tested it on Ubuntu, my pc is little endian and accepted by wireshark by using   `sum+=*(unsigned char*)addr;` and it is false to left shift 8 bits on a little endian pc. I got no bigEndian one,so I did't test it.I think you right.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short is at-least 16 bits, there's no guarantee that' it's not 32 or 64 bits.
you should be using uint_16t from <stdint.h>

you kind of need to shift, the last add would be

```
{
    uint16_t tmp=0;
    memcpy(addr,&tmp,1);
    sum += tmp;
}
```

which preserves the alignment, so, on a little endian machhine that's not shifted 
but on a big-endian it is compared to it's aligment as a char.

```
sum += ( *addr && *((uint16_t*)"\xff"));
```

but that code may not work unless you have some trick to word-align the string.

Be aware that the result is in network byte order, so 
if you need it in host byte order use the 
ntohs() function to convert it.

```
foo=compute_checksum(blah,blah_size);
printf("the internet checksum is %04h\n",(int)ntohs(foo));
```

Comment: "on the magic of symetry."  I don't get it. Network byte is bigEndian, if there is a odd byte, just add it and no need to change it to XX00 ? just add 00XX ? e.g. 0x123456 => 1234+0056  could you explain it in details?

Comment: @JS1 yeah, I was a bit confused, there and mis-read the original post.and the RFC. have made corrections.

Comment: @Jasen No worries.  I just didn't want incorrect information out there.  There are a lot of implementations of IP checksum that do exactly the RFC code without mentioning that the code only works for little endian.  If you do an internet search, most of them you find are that way.